# Which advanced mathematics book do you recommend for a college starter?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, calculus-of-variations, book-recommendation

I'm supposed to start my preparation for the college admission math exam so I'm looking for a good explanatory/textbook/problem book which covers most of or all of precalculus topics with a hint of calculus on an advanced level. By that I mean it should not just explain a topic, give a few minor examples and take off. Rather it should go in depth and explain deeper things about that particular thing. Is there such a book?

Comment: Ok in the first i meant shouldnt

Comment: OK, I edited your question to match your comment.

Comment: What exams? Different exams cover different material at different levels of difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Gelfand's Algebra, Trigonometry, Functions and Graphs.

Answer (score 0):

[Calculus by Michael Spivak](http://www.cambridge.org/es/academic/subjects/mathematics/real-and-complex-analysis/calculus-3rd-edition?format=HB&isbn=9780521867443) is one of the best textbooks I've ever seen. It provides leisurely explanations, a profusion of examples, a wide range of exercises and plenty of illustrations in an easy-going approach that enlightens difficult concepts and rewards effort.